# Cannot replace keyword using PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace 'keyword' in <img *..keyword..*/> using PHP regular expressions.

```
$content = '&lt;img alt="hello" src="http://frbird.qiniudn.com/topic/150609/5576a8837fd32e3b4ece5f6b-hd.jpg"&gt;';

$content = preg_replace('/(&lt;img\s(?!&gt;)*?)(hello)((?!&gt;)*&gt;)/U', '$1%&&&&&%$3', $content);
```

I can't replace 'hello'.  Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: If it is fixed keyword, you don'n need `regex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First translate the `&lt;` and `&gt;` tokens from the source string into `<` and `>`. That way they are far easier to handle. Then do the `preg_replace()` and translate them back again in the target string.

```
$src= strtr('&lt;img alt="hello" src="http://frbird.qiniudn.com/topic/150609/5576a8837fd32e3b4ece5f6b-hd.jpg"&gt;',array('&lt;'=>'<','&gt;'=>'>'));
$trg = strtr(preg_replace('/(<img[^>]*")(hello)(".*)/', '$1xxxxx$3', $src),array('<'=>'&lt;','>'=>'&gt;'));
echo $trg;
```

Not very elegant but it will do the trick.

Comment: thx! I try use html_entity_decode into < or > is good idea!  i didnt think of it

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to handle HTML (even escaped as it is) using a RegEx. Examples: [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Parse the fragment using SimpleXML/DOM, and look for attributes that way.

```
<?php
$string = html_entity_decode('&lt;img alt="hello" src="http://frbird.qiniudn.com/topic/150609/5576a8837fd32e3b4ece5f6b-hd.jpg"&gt;');

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML(
    $string,
    LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD
);

$attr = $dom->documentElement->removeAttribute('alt');

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I guess you're right. I've added a basic example using DOMDocument

Comment: the same as above, it was suceed, but my project does not apply to DOM, it need to use regexp, thx!